# Techniques for drawing spritesheets in OpenGL with shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, sprite-sheet

I'm learning OpenGL with right now and I'd like to draw some sprites to the screen from a sprite sheet. I'm note sure if I'm doing this the right way though.

What I want to do is to build a world out of tiles à la Terraria. That means that all tiles that build my world are 1x1, but I might want things later like entities that are 2x1, 1x2, 2x2 etc.

What I do right now is that I have a class named "Tile" which contains the tile's transform matrix and a pointer to its buffer. Very simple:

```
Tile::Tile(glm::vec2 position, GLuint* vbo)
{
    transformMatrix = glm::translate(transformMatrix, glm::vec3(position, 0.0f));
    buffer = vbo;
}
```

Then when I draw the tile I just bind the buffer and update the shader's UV-coords and vertex position. After that I pass the tile's transform matrix to the shader and draw it using glDrawElements:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttrib);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureAttrib);

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *tiles[i].buffer);

    glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(textureAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(tiles[i].transformMatrix));
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}

glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionAttrib);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureAttrib);
```

Could I do this more efficiently? I was thinking that I could have one buffer for 1x1 tiles, one buffer for 2x1 tiles etc. etc. and then just have the Tile class contain UVpos and UVsize and then just send those to the shader, but I'm not sure how I'd do that.

I think what I described with one buffer for 1x1 and one for 2x1 sounds like it would be a lot faster.

Comment: Using a sprite sheet as the texture for tiles and specifying the part of the sheet to use sounds like a good approach to take. Unfortunately I haven't worked with GLSL (just Cg and HLSL), so I can't help with the *how*. Have you tried searching around for examples on how to set shader parameters?

Comment: I know how to set values within the shader, it's done by the three lines above glDrawElements. The problem is that I need to pass 4 uv-coord pairs to the shader since it's done by a per-vertex basis. I don't know how I would go about binding a buffer and then sending the uv-data afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I do this more efficiently?

I don't think you could do it *less* efficiently. You are binding a whole buffer object for each quad. You are then uploading a matrix. For *each quad.*

The way tilemap drawing (and only the *map*, not the entities) normally works is that you build a buffer object that contains some portion of the visible screen's tiles. Empty space is rendered as a transparent tile. You then render *all* of the tiles for that region of the screen, all in one drawing call. You provide one matrix for all of the tiles in that region.

Normally, you'll have some number of such visible regions, to make it easy to update the tiles for that region when they change. Regions that go off-screen are re-used for regions that come on-screen, so you fill them with new tile data.

Comment: That's why I am asking.. I've read a bunch of tutorials but none of the ones I found that aren't using glBegin only draws one face. I didn't think about the fact that I could bind more things into one buffer though. Thanks